# Cocoa webview iframe (objective c)

Tags: html, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, webview

Good day!

I have an html page with iframe src.... in there. I need to get all HTML content of this frame to NSString.

Could you please advice the best way to do it without redirecting the webview to the src?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can feed in an html text in an [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsattributedstring/1535412-initwithhtml?language=objc) and extract the string from there.

```
NSAttributedString * attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

NSString *finalString = [attrString string];
```

Comment: There's no iframe html source, it is getting loaded dynamically by the WebView.

Comment: the webView has a property mainFrameDocument. It gives you the DOMDocument. Same thing as Javascript document. https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/webview/1408470-mainframe?language=objc.

Comment: mainframe does not include html of iFrame.

Comment: As far as I see, you have to redirect the iframe to the web view, extract the string and concatenate does two string together. Because the iframe is a different webpage after all.

Comment: That's what I want to avoid since the iframe can be loaded only once. It is a cross-domain iframe, that's why the xss protection does not allow me to get the html source.